# Android studio make jar file with dependencies with assets and jniLibs folder

Tags: android, jar, build.gradle

I want to use android studio to make a library project to a jar file which contains many jar file and it have assets folder and jniLibs folder.

How can to make a jar file with dependencies which contain all folders of jar file, assets and jniLibs folder.

Comment: You need to create [Android Library Project (Module)](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) if want to include assets etc.

Comment: I need to create jar file with asset folder.